# How do you find the proper separation between two spacetime points?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Suppose you had two points in space-time A and B, where A = (t1, χ1, θ1, φ1) and B = (t1, χ2, θ1, φ1). How would you use the FLRW metric to find the proper separation? In this case the points occur simultaneously (t1=t2), but I am really not sure how to do this? I've tried using the link below, but not sure how to do it for the specific cases of A and B?

[https://people.ast.cam.ac.uk/~pettini/Intro%20Cosmology/Lecture03.pdf](https://people.ast.cam.ac.uk/%7Epettini/Intro%20Cosmology/Lecture03.pdf)

ds is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is $R(t)(\chi_2-\chi_1)$. To see how this follows from the FLRW metric, note that $dt=0$, since by hypothesis these two points are located on the same constant-time hypersurface. Thus

$$
ds^2|_{t=cte} = -R^2[d\chi^2 + S_k^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)]\,.
$$

Now, the $t=\text{constant}$ hypersurfaces of the FLRW metric are maximally symmetric. This means that the distance between two points cannot depended on their overall orientation. This allows us to take $\theta=\phi=\text{constant}$, and therefore $d\theta=d\phi=0$. So

$$
ds^2|_{t=cte} = - R^2 d\chi^2\,. 
$$

Integrating both sides and using the fact that the proper distance is minus $ds^2$ (due to -2 metric signature) you arrive at the desired result. In short: in a homogeneous and isotropic space (which is the case in hand) the physical distance between two points at the same t=constant surface is just given by their comoving distances multiplied by the scale factor.

There is a less heuristic (but qualitatively equal) derivation which relies on the existence of Killing vectors. For that you write

$$
\Delta s = \int\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}
$$
and use the FLRW metric in the integral. Then, you impose that $\Delta s$ is invariant under the action of the Killing vectors of the spacetime. The final result is the same as the one given above. I will not give the details, but I can point to a reference where this is done.